# dealloc not called when i used addChildViewController

Tags: iphone, ios5, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, dealloc

i am using below code to add view as `addChildViewController`.

```
VideoListVC * videoListVC = [[VideoListVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VideoListVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:videoListVC];
navController.view.frame = self.view_Container.bounds;
videoListVC.view.frame = navController.view.bounds;

[self addChildViewController:navController];
[navController didMoveToParentViewController:self]
[self.view_Container  addSubview:navController.view];
```

`self is MenuVC` in which i add multiple `ViewControllers` as `childview`.  i called `MenuVC` as `pushViewController` So when i am in `MenuVC` i can see `VideoListVC` as child view. When i called `popViewControllerAnimated` that time `dealloc` method not called of `MenuVC` as well as  `VideoListVC`.  So the problem is `ViewController` memory not release and Apps memory continuously increase due to this. And finally app crash when i surt app around continuously `20 to 25 min`.

what is the way to resolved this ?? i had tried `removeFromParentViewController` but not getting any success.

Any thing is wrong in my code to  `addChildViewController` ??

Comment: Forget the last comment: WTH is this?: `UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] videoListVC];`? I don't believe a UINavigationController responds to this method.

Comment: @Abizern yes . it was my mistake. now see this. any idea ?

Comment: rather than adding the navigation controller as a child view controller (since it is taking up the whole screen) display it modally. Present it with `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and dismiss it with `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`

Comment: @Abizern my looks like Tabbar. at the bottom side 13 menu options display like tab and it will be horizontal screen.  when i click on each item new viewcontroller will be open on remaining screen area. so i can open it "presentViewController:animated:completion".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your second line should be

```
UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:videoListVC];
```

2) In case you don't use ARC, you should release your VideoListVC and navController at the end, because videoListVC is retained due to the initWithRootViewController call, and navController is retained due to addChildViewController.

3) I don't know if this is important, but Listing 14-1 of Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) shows another sequence when adding a childVC:

```
 [self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
 content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController]; // 2
 [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
 [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. i am trying your way.  ARC is on in My App.

Comment: done. from the "Topic : Implementing a Custom Container View Controller" in reference link . Thanks

Comment: "because videoListVC is retained due to the initWithRootViewController call" No, it's the `alloc` that returns a retained instance.

Comment: @Tafkadasoh as per my question when i "popViewControllerAnimated" OR add another "childviewControleler" than "dealloc" method not called so application memory continuously increase and finally app crash.

Comment: @newacct Yes, of course alloc returns a retained instance. But as initWithRootViewController retains videoListVC, you can safely release the instance after this call without dealloc being called.

Comment: @Coder: I mean: What did you change in your code to fix your problem?

Comment: @Tafkadasoh i have implement the code according to the tipic "Listing 14-1" & "Listing 14-2" in your sugetion link. Remove child viewcontroller code of mine was not proper so when i move from 1 UIViewController to 2nd UIViewController than - dealloc method not called .